# What do we think of "Alternative to" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/393009/80670), where the user simply did this:

> http://alternativeto.net/software/games-for-windows---live/
>
> Most of them integrate in games explorer anyway.

Are we against just saying "Go to Alternative.to"? To me it just seems like a really low quality and lazy answer, almost like saying "Go google it"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same as sending people to a search engine with the keywords already plugged in for them.

Those keywords being along the lines of:

- {product name} alternative
- {product name} "better than"

It is low quality and it is more of a comment instead of a full-fledged answer.

But also it's a signal that the question it hangs on is not constructive. Of the "look through a directory for me for I have chosen to give up on this life and want for nothing more than people to turn the page on my world as I suckle on the unpeeled grapes that feed me from on high" type that is just "I want X but *free*".

That question kind be lazy.

Comment: What course of action would you suggest taking with these answers?

Comment: Flag as not an answer and it will be converted to a comment.